# .NET library for laying out graphs

Tags: c#, graphs, graphviz

I am trying to find a c# .NET library for computing layouts of directed/undirected graphs. I only need the library to produce the layout (return the positions of the nodes), not render anything.

I am currently experimenting with Graphviz, but it has lots of dependencies for rendering to images that I really don't need.

Is there anything very light weight that has no dependencies? so is easily included with my application?

Comment: Do you need edge routing also, or just node placement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as the edges define how the nodes are positioned? But yes, I would like to be able to define a number of nodes and how they're linked together via edges, and then get back the layout positions of each node after layout.

Comment: Note that most/all of the Graphviz dependencies listed here (http://www.graphviz.org/download/source/) are marked as optional.  You could ask the Graphviz forum (https://forum.graphviz.org/) what a minimal package might require. p.s. I was trying to ask if you needed the edge layouts/placement

Comment: Have you seen this one?
https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout